# 404s on Some Pages After Re-Deploying War to Tomcat

Tags: linux, tomcat

I have a an app which I deploy to Tomcat 8 running on Redhat in dev, QA and production environments.  Occasionally when deploying to dev or QA, but nearly every time when deploying to production (copying the WAR file to the webapps directory), some pages on the site return 404s.  Neither reloading the app or restarting tomcatd have any effect, but rebooting the server resolves the problem.  There is nothing in the Tomcat logs that points to problems when deploying or starting the app, and unfortunately I have limited access to effectively diagnose anything on the server itself.  Has anyone ever come across this?

**Edit:**

I should also add that the same pages do not produce 404s every time.

Comment: Are you sure that Tomcat is using autodepoloyment (autoDeploy=true)?

Comment: @ALex_hha, yes, the app successfully deploys, and only a handful of pages return 404s.

Comment: Maybe some proxy (nginx/varnish/apache) behind tomcat?